.dwg visible in layer panel, not on map
I receive a .dwg file with a drawing of an installations at a particular address. Ideally, I'd use this file to add some other stuff in QGIS Grenoble.
So, I use the DWG/DXF import thing:

source drawing: filepath/drawing.dwg,
CRS: 28992 (like the rest of my layers),
target package: filepath/drawing.gpkg,
press import,
wait, and
load layers.

And then the file does load into the layer panel, but I cannot see it on my map. Not even when it's the top layer.
When I merge the .dwg into one layer, I do get a group (named drawing) with the layers hatches, lines, polylines, texts, and points. Of these, only hatches has attribute table-contents. I am not quite sure what to do with this information.
I'm not the only one with this issue, so I've tried (per another question) to use a different importer, in my case AnotherDXFImporter, which has not made things better.
I've also changed the colour of the layer, no dice.
Does anyone have any more suggestions?
EDIT
Have found the layers! Loading all the layers separately and then zooming to group. Now still have to move and scale from three countries over.

Please upload the DXF file for a test.

Could be lots of things.  You assigned a CRS to a DWG that is not referencing that CRS.  The DWG references a local grid.  The CRS you assigned is just the wrong one...What happens if you zoom to those features?

Zooming to layer doesn't change anything. Could I find out the CRS from the file without being the file producer or being able to read the file? The CRS is the one that's most often used for this bit of the world.

With DWG/DXF it's not uncommon to have coordinate in other unit than meter (centimeter notably) while QGIS CRS expect meter (I guess this is also true with feet/inches) soi even if the CRS is right it's displayed at the place at the wrong size...
